# How can I load a skybox dds file into paint.NET for editing?

Tags: graphics, xna, paint.net, skybox

So I have a skybox dds file that I have implemented in XNA 4.0. However I would like to customise the file and am not sure how I can edit it correctly. I have managed to open the file in paint.NET, the only problem is that the image displayed in paint.NET is a square of the map but surely there should be another 5 images that can fit together to make the box shape?

Comment: Maybe there are different layers, could it be?

Comment: Yeah I think it was something to do with that, had to take a completely different approach as I couldn't figure out how to dismantle it and put it back together